# Make Excel xml (2003) format styles (StyleId="s55" and AutoFitHeight="0") stable

Tags: excel

In order to store casual spreadsheet content in the version control system, we chose the old Excel 2003 xml format.

Problem is that following xml elements are instable:

- //ExcelWorkbook/ActiveSheet
- //Worksheet/Table/Column/@ss:Width  <- only when switching between versions
- //Worksheet/Table/Row/@ss:AutoFitHeight="0"
- //Worksheet/Table/Row/Cell/@ss:StyleID="s62"  <- This gets toggled everywhere even if just one word was changed. Extreme case is merged cells where some kind of hash seems to be incorporated (StyleID="s38721091765")
- //Worksheet/WorksheetOptions/Selected
- //Worksheet/WorksheetOptions/TopRowVisible
- //Worksheet/WorksheetOptions/Unsynced
- //Worksheet/WorksheetOptions/Panes/Pane/ActiveRow
- //Worksheet/WorksheetOptions/Panes/Pane/ActiveCol

Example diff of actually unchanged data:[image: diff view of xml source of Excel 2003 file which marks some StyleID as changed and claims line insertions/deletions where actually just StyleID changed]

Question: How to make excel more stable, especially how to force StyleID and AutoFitHeight?

Answer (score 0):

*Inconvenient* solutions for some of the problems:

**//Worksheet/Table/Row/Cell/@ss:StyleID="s62"**: It is possible to add a very first worksheet which has all styles in ordered manner

[image]

**//Worksheet/Table/Row/@ss:AutoFitHeight="0"**: It is possible to click on cells > format > auto-adapt row height.

**//Worksheet/WorksheetOptions/Panes/Pane/ActiveRow** and similar: It is possible to select the same cells as before before saving

Comment: I will not accept this answer because I hope someone has a more convenient one.